# How to let a user duplicate a view

Tags: ios, swift

I've a countdown app, it counts the time towards and since a date that the user chooses, and would like to know how to allow a user to pick more than one countdowns.

I'm thinking if there is a way to let the user duplicate the view, but I could be far from right, I'm new to this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question, as stated, provides very little information. What have you tried so far? What is the nature of your "Countdowns"?

Comment: I literally have no idea what to try. My app is a single view application, all the user does is choose a date, and the view shows the time difference between now and the date. How can I make two dates saved and swipe between them?

Comment: Now it makes more sense. By swipe between them, you mean like a horizontal scroll view with paging enabled? (think of the Photos app when not in thumbnail mode)

Comment: Exactly that, but with countdowns. Basically a way to replicate the first view, but changing only one variable, the date.

Answer (score 1):

Given the requirements that you mention on your question and the follow up comments, I think perhaps the best is to use a horizontally scrolling [collection view](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CollectionViewBasics/CollectionViewBasics.html), with each cell taking up the whole screen.

*(before the advent of autolayout, I would have recommended a `UISCrollView` with the content size varying at runtime as you add pages, but setting up `UISCrollView` correctly with autolayout is a steep learning curve. `UICollectionView` and `UITableView` take care of this for you behind the scenes)*.

The setup would be like this:

1. In the storyboard, embed your view controller in a navigation controller, so you can (perhaps) have your "Add Countdown" button as the navigation bar's right bar button item.
2. Next (still in the storyboard), add a collection view to your view controller and wire any outlets/delegates/etc.
3. Implement your data source so that it reflects how many countdown objects you currently have, and set up the "add" button so that when tapped, it creates a new counter and refreshes the collection view.

Comment: What if I have a fully developed single view controller, can I put that as a cell?

Comment: Here is an idea of what my app looks like https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/daycount-days-since-or-until/id1121088244?mt=8

Comment: Perhaps. `UICollectionViewCell` _is_ a subclass of `UIView`. You could instantiate your countdown view controller and add its main view as a subview of the collection view cell.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll try further

Comment: Getting collection view to work will take some effort, but it pays off. Good luck!